# How to query by xpath under html element

Tags: javascript, html

Find all input under menu, expected `2` , but got `3`.

```html
<div>
  <div class="menu">
    1<input type="text">
    2 <input type="text">
  </div>
  3 <input type="text">
</div>
```

```js
var menu = document.querySelector('.menu')
var xpath = "//input"
var arr =[]
var result = document.evaluate(xpath, menu , null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
var nodes = result.iterateNext();
while (nodes){
    arr.push(nodes)
    nodes=result.iterateNext();
}
console.assert(arr.length === 2)
// Assertion failed: console.assert
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following xpath:

```
const xpath = "//div[@class='menu']//input"
```

`xpath = "//input"` will find all input elements on the page